# Como adicionar um ImageView em um RelativeLayout em runtimer?

Tags: java, android-layout

Como faço para adicionar um `ImageView` em tempo de execução ao `LinearLayout` ou até mesmo uma `TableLayout`?

Answer (score 1):

Ambos os `LinearLayout` e `TableLayout` herdam de `ViewGroup`. O `ViewGroup` é a classe que tem a capacidade de agregar e compor hierarquia de `View's`.

No caso do `LinearLayout` basta chamar `addView` passando sua `ImageView`. É opcional passar um índice ou um `LayoutParams`, ai ficará a cargo da situação.

No caso do `TableLayout` você irá precisar englobar sua `ImageView` em um `TableRow` antes e adicionar o `TableRow` ao `TableLayout`.

Uma recomendação que dou é verificar a regras de `layout_width` e `layout_height` para usar no `LayoutParams` do `ImageView` e/ou do `TableRow`.

No caso do `LinearLayout` verifique a orientação para evitar problemas.

Comment: ótimo, era o que eu precisava... obg.

Comment: @HerikR, se a resposta te ajudou, marque-a como certa, para não confundir membros achando que a resposta não é útil.

Comment: Aqui diz que preciso de 15 pontos para votar a favor.

Comment: @Herik, basta clicar na "seta" verde, indicando que esta é a resposta correta.